# How to insert Null value to database if the user do not pick a date?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker to allow user to select a date for input date.
One thing I was wondering, when user do not select any date from datepicker. It not show Null value in database, It show date format as 0000-00-00.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Date of Birth</label>
   <div data-date-viewmode="years" data-initialize="datepicker" data-value="null" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date="{{date('Y-m-d')}}" class="input-append date dpYears col-md-8">
     <input type="text" name="birth_date" placeholder="{{date('Y-m-d')}}" size="16" class="form-control">
     <span class="add-on birhtdateDatepicker">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$('.dpYears').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    setDate: new Date()
});
```

Here is my insert code:

```
public function postClient(){
$input = Request::except('_token','photo','signature');
return $input;
    if (!empty($input) && is_array($input)) {
        $addNew = new Client();
      foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $addNew->$key = $value;
      }
    }
}
```

What I want is to insert Null value to database if user do not select a date.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: How is your insert code?...also, do you allow nulls on your table field??

Comment: Sure I did, in my table field, Type:date, Null:yes, Default:Null

Comment: Can i see your insert code??

Comment: Here is my insert code:
public function postClient(){
    $input = Request::except('_token','photo','signature');
    return $input;
        if (!empty($input) && is_array($input)) {
            $addNew = new Client();
        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            $addNew->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

you can set the initial value

```
$(".dpYears").datepicker("setDate", "");
```

Comment: I tried this, but it not working. Still get 0000-00-00 as before.

Comment: have you try set date to empty string ? 
$('.dpYears').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    setDate: ''
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$(".dpYears").datepicker("setDate", null);
```

Comment: What datepicker library did you used?

Comment: I used Bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to setDate(null) 
http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/